# How to read all files that name store in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python to read all find that path's of file store in text file such as (name_path.txt)

```
0_7\069A07.JPG;0
0_7\070A02.JPG;0
0_7\070A03.JPG;0
20_36\003A25.JPG;1
20_36\003A35.JPG;1
20_36\057A23.JPG;1
20_36\057A25.JPG;1
```

In which first element is path of file, and second element (seperated by ";") store label. Now I want to use python to get:

1. File path such as `0_7\069A07.JPG` and its label such as 0. (see in first row)

Could you help me to implement it? Thanks you so much
Update This is what I am doing

```
infile = "name_path.txt"
data = open(infile, "r").readlines()
# Create a dictionary list
for line in data:
    row = line.split(";");
    pathname=row[0]
    label=row[1]
```

Comment: *"Could you help me to implement it?"* Sure, but you'll have to give us a starting block, what code do you have so far? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Let check my update. Sorry I have go out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store your labels as the key and the paths in a list :

```
infile = "name_path.txt"
d={}
with open(infile, "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    path,label = line.split(";")
    d.setdefault(label,[]).append(path)
```

> **setdefault(key[, default])**
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

Comment: why not use a default dict? much better way to do that

Comment: @JohnRuddell For a simple task like this its better to refuse of importing an extra module when you can do it with built-in methods!